# "Incorrect syntax near ')'."

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2017, sqlconnection

I have a program that is to take a couple inputs and do stuff to them then store them in a local database (using SQL Server).

I have the following code for the connection:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
con.ConnectionString = ("Data Source=DESKTOP-PGHMM6M;Initial Catalog=LocalUsers;Integrated Security=True");

con.Open();

String st = "INSERT INTO data(Username,Password, Hash, EncryptedPassword)";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(st, con);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Username);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", textBox2.Text);         
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Hash", savedPasswordHash);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EncryptedPassword", FinalEncryptedPass);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

con.Close();
```

It fails at the `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` line, and throws this exception :

> Incorrect syntax near ')'

I'm not even really sure where to start, as I haven't done any of this since college (107 years ago). Can anybody help me get started? I've been scouring but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: You need to append the `VALUES()` clause at the end of the `INSERT`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `VALUES` clause will need to be within the insert statement string.  I would also recommend a `using` block instead of directly opening the `SqlConnection`, as will automatically close the connection upon exit whether by completion or error.  While technically there isn't a difference between using `String` and `string` as in your command text, `String` would most often be used to reference a class while `string` is typically used in object references such as the case here.

```
string connectionString = @"YourConnectionString";

string st = "INSERT INTO data(Username,Password, Hash, EncryptedPassword) VALUES (@Username, @Password, @Hash, @EncryptedPassword)";

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(st1, con);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Username);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", textBox2.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Hash", savedPasswordHash);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EncryptedPassword", FinalEncryptedPass);

    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your insert should look like this:

```
INSERT INTO data (Username, Password, Hash, EncryptedPassword) 
VALUES (@Username, @Password, @Hash, @EncryptedPassword)
```